# GNU autotooling, where to install shell functions?

Tags: directory-structure, function, autoconf, automake

I have a tiny project that configures and installs some shell scripts using GNU autotools.

Now, the scripts will have to source a common file containing some shell functions.

Where should this file be installed by `make install`?

According to "[Variables for Installation Directories](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)", `libexecdir` is for executable files (the file containing the shell functions is not an executable in itself) and `datadir` is for architecture-independent data (this file depends on the architecture).

Is there any precedent for using any of these two paths (or any other installation path) for installing a file containing only shell functions? These functions are not meant to be used separately at the moment.

Comment: `/usr/local/share` or `/usr/share`?

Comment: If you don't like `libexec` my second guess would be `/usr/local/lib/your_app`. After all it's a library, albeit one of shell functions.

Comment: While I can’t answer your second question, the answer to your first question is that *it’s up to you.* If following FHS/GNU standards is important to you, just decide for yourself whether shell functions seem more like data to you, or more like _executable programs to be run by other programs._ That said, I personally prefer to view them as code; in many ways, the interpreter executes a function just like it would run a standalone script – even though the invocation ritual and other details differ. Due to that, I use `pkglibexecdir` (or `libexecdir` if I want other packages to use them, too).

Answer (score -1):

Your functions to be installed are in the context of your shell.
*So store them there*: `~/.bash_functions`

Every time your shell loads, it loads commands, `~/.bashrc`, and even aliases, `~/.bash_aliases`. These are shell scripts which simply add commands to the shell PATH variable or set aliases. Shell scripts which define functions, to follow suit, should be defined here as well.

Then append a line to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` to ensure they are loaded for your terminal or just at the beginning of your shell scripts which depend on them:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then
    . ~/.bash_functions
fi
```

Append functions to the file as desired:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/.bash_functions file
function_one () {
    echo "hi"
}
function_two() {
...
```

Comment: The scripts are potentially to be installed system-wide, the functions are to be loaded from the script, and the functions are not for interactive use. Also, I don't use `bash`.